# JQuery vertical scroller

Tags: jquery

I am trying to recreate the effect seen on this site: http://zipdesign.co.uk/New-State-Entertainment. I have a basic understanding of how it works but am having trouble applying it to the site I am working on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the source of that particular site, I'd imagine it's using the jquery scrollTo plugin.

This essentially allows you to call $(selector).scrollTo() and the page with smoothly scroll to the selected element.

Comment: Looking through firebug it is indeed the scrollTo plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/news-scroller